# Creating a form for custom action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller: Distrib_controller, where I create a custom action create_contact. I created the page create_contact.html.erb and create the route as well.
When I try to open the page I have the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: distrib):
```

This is the first time I am creating a custom action form, apologies in advance if there are too many mistakes:
Controller

```rb
def create_contact
  @distrib = current_user.distribs.build(distrib_params)
  if @distrib.save
    redirect_to distribs_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def distrib_params
    params.require(:distrib).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :user_id, :telephone)
end
```

Form in `create_controller.html.erb`

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <%= form_with @distrib, url: distribs_save_contact_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email, placeholder: "email" %>
    <%= f.input :first_name, placeholder: "First name" %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, placeholder: "Last name" %>
    <%= f.input :telephone, placeholder: "Telephone" %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Custom route:

```rb
get 'distribs/create_contact'
post 'distribs/create_contact'
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: My bad, I changed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close already, there's just a few bits missing.

If you have this in your DistribsController:

```rb
class DistribsController < ApplicationController
  def create_contact
    @distrib = current_user.distribs.build(distrib_params)
    if @distrib.save
      redirect_to distribs_path
    else
      render "contact_form"
    end
  end

  def contact_form
    @distrib = current_user.distribs.build
  end

private

  def distrib_params
    params.require(:distrib).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :user_id, :telephone)
  end
end
```

This in `app/views/distribs/contact_form.html.erb`:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <%= form_for @distrib, url: distribs_create_contact_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "email" %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :telephone, placeholder: "Telephone" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and this in your `config/routes.rb`

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post "distribs/create_contact"
  get "distribs/contact_form"
end
```

...it should accomplish what is sounds like you want. The primary missing pieces here were that you weren't making a clear distinction between the action for creating the contact and the action for displaying the form, and that you were using a path helper for the `url` in the form that didn't appear to exist.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, I tried completing my code with your approach, and I get the following : `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: distrib):`
  
`app/controllers/distribs_controller.rb:123:in distrib_params'`
`app/controllers/distribs_controller.rb:146:in create_contact'`

Comment: That's probably happening because your original form used `form_with` instead of `form_for`, which I didn't realize when I copied from your question until after I posted. I updated my answer shortly after posting, so double check that you have `form_for`, reload the form and try it again. Sorry about that.

Comment: I just changed the form_with to form_for and reload, the same error is showing up. Could there be another reason ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the rest of your code, but that error is happening in the `create_contact` action the params don't contain the key `distrib`. You can see what params _are_ being sent over in the logs where you're running the Rails server and also in your browsers dev tools in the Network section. It might also be worth double check what `@distrib` is being set to in the `contact_form` action.

Comment: Thing is, i don't even get to see the form. I try to open the page  `/create_contact` and get the error before the form gets to display. So just to confirm the weblink is to create_contact or to contact_form ?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's the route for the form to post to. You'll want to visit `/distribs/contact_form` in your browser.

Comment: Okee I will keep on checking what I am not doing well. Thank you for putting me on this direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197765/discussion-between-mason-stewart-and-etienne).

Answer (score 1):

When you do this `distrib_params` it throws the error if you have no "params[:distrib]" (that's the `params.require(:distrib)` for). It's ok to not have that param if you do a GET request, it's not present until you send the form data.

If you want to use the same action for both GET and POST request, then don't call that "distrib_params" unless you have a POST request (also don't call `@distrib.save` since it will always fail).

Personally, I wouldn't do that, I would do something like @Mason 
Stewart posted but following some conventions:

Use "new" and "create" actions on your controller

```
class DistribsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @distrib = current_user.distribs.build(distrib_params)
    if @distrib.save
      redirect_to distribs_path
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def new
    @distrib = current_user.distribs.build
  end

private

  def distrib_params
    params.require(:distrib).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :user_id, :telephone)
  end
end
```

Change your form view name to "new.html.erb" (to match the action name) and change the form_for helper so rails inferes the path from the object:

```
<%= form_for @distrib do |f| %>
```

Change your route to use rails' "resources" helper:

```
resources :distrib #then you can go to /distribs/new
```

Try to follow rails' conventions whenever possible.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I could not use the classic NEW and CREATE method because they area already serving a specific type of input. Long story short, I need to create another method that does what the initial NEW and CREATE do.